# Google Script timeout after 6 min

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I want to list all the folderName and their folderID present in a team Drive(more than 3000 folders). I am using speedsheet and running following code in script-

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.appendRow(['Name','File-Id']);


//change the folder ID below to reflect your folder's ID (look in the URL when you're in your folder)
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder ID');
    var contents = folder.getFolders();

    var cnt = 0;
    var folder;

    while (contents.hasNext()) {
        var folder = contents.next();
        cnt++;

           data = [
                folder.getName(),
                folder.getId(),
            ];

            sheet.appendRow(data);
    };
}
```

But this is getting Error Exceeded maximum execution time which is 6 min by default.

I tried adding triggers from script app, but after triggering it get start from beginning and script still ends after 6min.

How to add a triggers which starts from where it left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The slow part of this script is the repeated call to `sheet.appendRow()`. You can speed this up by pushing the results to an array and setting the values at the end of the loop, rather than appending a row on each iteration of the `while` loop.*

#### More Information:

Using the built-in services such as `SpreadsheetApp` often can be slow when making many changes to a sheet in a short space of time. You can combat this by minimising the number of calls to the built-in Apps Script services as possible, relying on pure JavaScript to do your processing.

#### Code Change:

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {
   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  //change the folder ID below to reflect your folder's ID (look in the URL when you're in your folder)
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
  let contents = folder.getFolders()

  let cnt = 0
  let data = [['Name','File-Id']]

  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    folder = contents.next()
    cnt++

    data.push([
      folder.getName(),
      folder.getId(),
    ])
  }
  sheet.insertRows(sheet.getMaxRows(), data.length)
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, 2).setValues(data)
}
```

**Code changes:**

- `data` is declared as an array initialised with the header row, as opposed to appending it directly to the sheet
- On each iteration of the loop, the current folder's name and ID is appended to the `data` array as a new row of data.
- After all folders have been looped through, the number of rows in the sheet is extended by the number of rows in `data` so to not hit an out of bounds error
- All rows inside `data` are added to the sheet using `setValues()`.

In my test environment, I had the following set up:

- Drive folder containing 3424 folders

Using the `appendRow()` method inside the while loop, execution took 1105.256 seconds (or 18 minutes)

Using `push()` with the `.setValues()` method outside the loop, execution took 4.478 seconds.

#### References:

- [Class Range - setValues() | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: yeah you are right, by using .setValues() outside the loop, it did took less time, but in my case it threw an error after 40sec saying "Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.". stating somethings wrong with the insertRows line.

Comment: Aer you sure it's the `insertRows()` line and not the `getRange()` line? Try adding a SpreadsheetApp.flush() after the `insertRows()` call. Also - how many rows does the sheet have? add a `console.log(sheet.getLastRow()` and a `console.log(data.length)` before the `insertRows` call and see what the values are before it

Comment: this time, it showing 2 numbers in log, first is 0, which is for console.log(sheet.getLastRow()) and second is 3739, for console.log(data.length) which i guess is number of folders in that folder. but again, same error, rows out of bound, sheet have 8000 rows, i added them manually.

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet please?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bkYnjvlJElPkX8m8wcg4Q6y1_7kVLIt9fwZiWEhaJ-E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: idk what sanitised copy means. i am new, sorry.

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name, the two functions are both called `listFilesInFolder`. Try rename them so they have different names and try again. Make sure your Drive folder ID is correct too, and let me know if you hit the same error.

Comment: i deleted the old code, same error i also authenticated that and added test folder id, kindly take a look at that. but same error

Comment: @AnkitKumar I don't know why in your script `sheet.getLastRow()` seems to be returning 0, but I have updated my code to rectify this, please let me know if this works for you

Comment: ITS WORKING!! and the only difference is those square brackets in 'let data' . thanks for helping. i really dont know much about programming, starting to do some stuff on my own, glad to know there are people like you who help others.